# Как правильно сформулировать коррелирующий подзапрос SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Изучаю SQL на примере СУБД sqlite3.
Есть база данных `albums(band TEXT, album TEXT, year INT);`. Я хочу одним запросом получить все альбомы групп у которых есть хотя бы один альбом подходящий под шаблон `'The%'`. Я понимаю как получить названия групп у которых есть такой альбом.

```
SELECT DISTINCT band
FROM albums
WHERE album LIKE 'The%'
```

Возвращает:

```
Queen
Red Hot Chili Peppers
Madness
```

Но когда я пытаюсь получить все альбомы этих групп...

```
SELECT *
FROM albums
WHERE band = 
(SELECT DISTINCT band
FROM albums
WHERE album LIKE 'The%');
```

получаю только альбомы квинов:

```
Queen|Queen|1973
Queen|Queen II|1974
Queen|Sheer Heart Attack|1974
...
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `WHERE band IN` вместо `WHERE band = ` не понятно почему он вам просто ошибку не выдал, видать sqlite такую ошибку не умеет писать, что в = более одной записи с одной из сторон

Comment: Спасибо, мил человек!